# Convert String of words/letters into an Integer

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, integer, converters, unityscript

Today I've finally decided to make an account, in hope for some aid in an issue I've spent the last few hours hunting. (I've spent the past couple hours hunting down a response, from Google to here to Unity Answers. [Here's everything that I've found so far, which doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIHNV.png))

---

What I'm looking for, is to change a string of purely words/letters into an integer. Therefore "Hello World", would be translated into a string of numbers accordingly. This may be surprising, but this is a lot harder than it sounds. I've found a way to do essentially everything but, thus far.

Presumably the best way would be to get the ASCII value of each letter in the string, and put them all together into a single integer. (No sequences or need to separate them, but one single number.) I have no idea where to get started or how to do that, however. Really anything that you think would work, preferably as short-hand and un-bothersome as possible.

To be as clear as possible, I need to take the letter-only variable "example" and transmorph it to be a integer/only a sequence of numbers.

Comment: What is the sequence of numbers supposed to be? If you want to go back from the number to the string, this will not work unless you create an array of the ASCII values. What is the purpose of this? In JS, getting the ASCII value of a character is as simple as `"n".charCodeAt(0)`

Comment: The OP may want to edit the tags.

Comment: I'm sorry, but unless I'm horribly mistaken; this is for JavaScript, not Java. JavaScript in Unity, to be exact. Also, the numbers are meant to be in one single sequence. A single integer.

Comment: @Brennan I can not use **charCodeAt**, as that is limited to translating a single character in unicode. I need to translate an entire string of words/letters, into a single integer. _(Sorry, would've just edited my above comment but it wouldn't let me.)_

Comment: Yes, so you would loop over every character in the string, getting the charCode at every position, and append the charcode to a string. But again, why are you doing this? It sounds a bit nefarious. And you are correct about this being Javascript, I read your code wrong. But for clarity: `var int_string = ""; for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++); int_string+=string.charCodeAt(i);` will give you a string with all of the ascii codes of the string you are translating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to convert an arbitrary string into a random seed, then why not try `randomSeed.GetHashCode()`? That will return an `int` value suitable for setting the seed, which would produce the same number each time the same string is entered.

Comment: This is an infinitely better, and simpler solution for what I was looking for. Best of it all, it requires no tweaking for when I switch my UnityScript/JavaScript project over to C#. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all characters, get their charCode and chain them together. The first method splits the string into single chars and uses Array.reduce:

```
var str = 'qwertzuiop';
var num = parseInt(str.split('').reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b.charCodeAt(0);}, '');
```

The second calls Array.forEach on the string, because it has numerical indices and a length property.

```
var num = ''; [].forEach.call(str, function(c) {num += c.charCodeAt(0);});
    num = parseInt(num);
```

In stoneaged browsers you have to use `for-loops` instead.